# TensorFlow installation problem in Python 3.4-64 bit-Win10

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10, 64-bit, python-3.4

I'm trying to install TensorFlow. I followed the first and second phase of https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip correctly. But I have a problem with the phase " 3. Install the TensorFlow pip package". While virtual environment(venv) is active, i'm trying to do `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`
but i have an error which is  `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

I'm trying to install using .whl also, but I can't find exact file for Python 3.4 64bit Win10. But in the website of tensorflow, they noted that "Requires Python 3.4, 3.5, or 3.6".

So why I got this error and how can I solve it? What am I doing wrong? 
If you have an idea or experience on the subject, I would be glad if you share with me.
Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to install with pip3**

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: it didn't work for me. I uninstalled python 3.4 and install python 3.5, now it works.